# Store values in table as new row after OLS iteration

Tags: python, forecasting, tabular

I have a problem with my code: I have some time series data that I want to use to predict the value of an exogenous variable, which I am doing with an OLS:

```
# Get OLS
OLS = sm.OLS.from_formula('A ~ B + C + D + E', df1['2013/11/08':'2014/03/25']).fit()
OLS.summary()
```

Then I would use the results of the OLS to predict

```
# Get a 5 days forecast
param = OLS.params
regr = OLS.rsquared
pred = param[0] + param[1] * df1['B'] + param[2] * df1['C'] + param[3] * df1['D'] + param[4] * df1['E']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pred, columns=['Z'])
df3 = pd.concat([df2, df0], axis=1)
diff = df3['Z'] - df3['X']
df4 = pd.DataFrame(diff, columns=['Difference'])
df_diff_5days = df4['26/03/2014':'30/03/2014']
df_diff_5days
```

This works for me, as it gives me the output looking like this:

```
           Difference
2014-03-26  5
2014-03-27  6
2014-03-28 -3
2014-03-29  9
2014-03-30 -7
```

What I want is to have a loop, that iterates through the OLS and the new differences as output, always increasing the time horizon by one day (which means for the next iteration use df1['2013/11/08':'2014/03/26'] and get differences for 2014-03-27 - 2014-03-31) and store the results in a table that should look like this:

```
    2014-03-26 2014-03-27 2014-03-28 2014-03-29 2014-03-30 2014-03-31 2014-04-01 ...
         5          6         -3          9         -7
                    2         -1         10         -5          2
        ...
```

I already created the first row using this command:
    columns = pd.date_range('26/03/2014', periods=1000, freq='H')

```
df_err = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
df_error = df_err.append(df_diff_5days['Difference'])
df_error
```

But now I am stuck. Is there any possibility to automatically increasing the horizon of the OLS by one day, shifting the range of df4 by one day and storing each outcome in a new row in the table df_error?

If I just change the dates by hand, I only get the same table, with another row, but the first one is deleted.